# List of ModelExpression to TagHelper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I want to create a custom taghelper which creates display function for a model with multiple values. However, I want to occasionally ignore some values of the model. So ideally I would like to pass a list of ModelExpression values to the taghelper so I know which ones to ignore on the output. This does not seem to be possible.

Example code to demonstrate:

Model to display:

```
public class Field
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public short Order { get; set; }
        public string Class { get; set; }
```

In taghelper:

```
        [HtmlAttributeName("asp-for")]
        public ModelExpression For { get; set; }

        [HtmlAttributeName("asp-ignore")]
        public List<ModelExpression> Ignore { get; set; }
```

In View:

```
@model MvcProject.Models.Field

@{
}

<custom-displayforModel asp-for="@Model" asp-ignore="new List<ModelExpression>() { Model.Id, Model.Class}"">
    </custom-displayforModel>
```

It is possible to pass items like Model.Id and Model.Class individually but as a list I can only produce errors.

`List<ModelExpression>() { Model.Id, Model.Class}` produces
`Cannot convert type 'int' to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ModelExpression`

`List<ModelExpression>() { Model.Id as ModelExpression }` produces
`Cannot convert type 'int' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ModelExpression' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion`

`List<ModelExpression>() { (ModelExpression)Model.Id}` produces
`Cannot convert type 'int' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ModelExpression'`

Am I wrong? Is there a possible way to pass these values somehow to the taghelper? Should I try to get and pass the Display name of the properties instead?

Answer (score 1):

`ModelExpression` accepts any type. You can change `List<ModelExpression>` to `ModelExpression`.

```
    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-ignore")]
    public ModelExpression Ignore { get; set; }
```

In the view, pass a list.

```
@{
    var list = new List<Field>
    {
        new Field{ Id=1, Class ="class"}
    };
}

<custom-displayforModel asp-for="@Model" asp-ignore="@list"> </<custom-displayforModel>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this is not exactly what I searched for. My problem is that I want to send a list or an array on values WITHIN the model, sometimes a multiple different types. So I would like to pass the values of Model.Id and Model.Class to the taghelper as ModelExpressions or something that can be used almost like ModelExpressions

Comment: That is not feasible, because ModelExpressions itself converts certain types. If you want to map multiple types of data at the same time, you can create a class to contain different types of data.